# Photos display from Google plus album feed using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am newbie to angularJS , trying to display all google plus public Album photos
on my new webpage, So far i tried is in plunker link, but its missing something to be Done,
here is the plunker link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GFEsToPj4zma5ur78Adt?p=info

Can anyone please help with this , i am guessing something went wrong in controller part , when i check console , it wont give any error

thanks in advance

/cheers

Comment: I'm not sure you can use angular routes in plunker.

Comment: Maybe it's better to commit this code in a github repo, and publish it in a github.io page (http://pages.github.com/). It'll be easier to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code that does what you want
https://github.com/tonylampada/picasa-angular/tree/gh-pages

Here you can see it in action
http://tonylampada.github.io/picasa-angular/

Nice pictures ;-)